# What is the difference between project(':projectName') {} and $projectRoot/projectName/build.gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

I see reference to a subproject as

```
project(':projectName') {}
```

inside $projectRoot/build.gradle

and I also see reference to a subproject with a seperate build such as $projectRoot/projectName/build.gradle

What is the difference?

**UPDATE**: Why would I define a subproject in

```
project(':projectName') {}
```

instead of creating a build file:

```
~/root/projectName/build.gradle
```

Or is there a reason to use both declarations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle offers flexibility here. Some teams prefer to maintain only one build script in the root folder (e.g. the Spring project maintains the whole Gradle build in one `build.gradle` file). Some others like to split things up and add subproject specific settings into a subproject specific build file.

To make things even more complex, you can mix both options. You can have a subproject Gradle file and additionally to that, make further configurations to this *subproject* in the *root project*.

Cheers,
René

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. But really hate the idea of mixing it all up to make things really complex ;-)